# Join 3 tables Hibernate & JPA

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have three tables and I want to join them and it's driving me crazy.

Tabels : **Task**
         **Project**
         **User**

They All have a **Many-To-Many** relationShip between them : like project has multiple users and vice versa and also Tasks have multiple users and vice versa and the same for project and users.

I'm trying to find a way to implement that in JPA & Hibernate and I have 2 choices : 
** 1 ** Join the 3 entities like this :

***Project*** :

```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
    cascade =
    {
            CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH,
            CascadeType.PERSIST
    },
    targetEntity = User.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "Collaborators", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ProjectFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "UserFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false))
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

***User*** :

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
            cascade =
                {
                        CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST
                },
                targetEntity = Project.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "Collaborators", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "UserFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ProjectFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false))
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

***Task*** :

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
        cascade =
        {
                CascadeType.DETACH,
                CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.REFRESH,
                CascadeType.PERSIST
        },
        targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "Collaborators", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TaskFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ProjectFk", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "User_id")
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Project, User> projectUserMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But here it dosn't seem to work

**2** : Create a 4th Entity and name it **Collaborator** and then try to find a way to implement this SQL query :

```
select * from (
select user.id, Project.id, Task.id
inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key
) collaborator
```

Any help would be **MUCH** apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just look through your configuration and find out a lot of errors and redundancies. Please research more about JPA Collection Mapping to understand deeply about that.

Comment: That's because I don't undrestand how to join these three tables.I did succeed easily at first with project and user but with a ternary association it's a bit hard.

Comment: *I don't use mappedBy cause I want to control the way delete operation happens.*: that's a big mistake you're doing. mappedBy and coltrolling the deletion don't have anything to do with eash other. In a bidirectional association one side **MUST** be the inverse side, and thus use mappedBy. You ammping in Task doesn't make much sense either. If you have three ManyToMany associations, you need 3 different join tables.

Comment: Thanks for the _mappedBy_ note. But that's what I'm running from. I don't want to make three join tables. I thought I would make 1 join table where it holds the _IDs_ of the 3 Tables like : **1_Project** / **1_Task** / **1_USER** as Indicated in the Last _SQL Query_.

Comment: @NeilStockton yeah that's what I meant. But I can't find a way to map that into an entity, like How to get the IDs and it must be as The sql statement states ! `inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key`. If you would give me an answer I will accepte it and Upvote it **now** (_Bribe_)

Comment: If the table has three columns, then it's not a join table between two entities, and you need to map it as an entity.

Comment: Yeah but How !@JBNizet

Comment: what's wrong with my answer? @MoatezBouhdid

Comment: Look at the comment on your response pls @thanhngo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be implemented like below:

**Project class**

```
 @Entity
public class Project extends ABaseEntity{

private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Collaborators",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Project_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable=false))
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

**User class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMA_USER")
public class User extends ABaseEntity {

private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        targetEntity = Project.class)
@JoinTable(name = "Collaborators",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Project_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false))
public Set<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
}
```

**Task class**

```
@Entity
public class Task extends ABaseEntity{

private Map<Project, User> projectUserMap = new HashMap<>();

@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@JoinTable(
        name = "Collaborators",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Task_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "Project_Id")
public Map<Project, User> getProjectUserMap() {
    return projectUserMap;
}

public void setProjectUserMap(Map<Project, User> projectUserMap) {
    this.projectUserMap = projectUserMap;
}
}
```

**What is wrong in your task class:**

```
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "User_id")
```

The @MapKeyJoinColumn is used to map the column for the key, here is Project entity.

```
@ElementCollection
```

is used if the value of the map is @Embeddable

```
@JoinTable
```

defines the relation between the entity class with entity defined in value of the Map (here is relation between Task and User).

```
 targetEntity = User.class
```

All targetEntity are redundant because you used collection with defined generic type.

Moreover, you don't have to configure 3 classes like this. As far as i understand, you just need a table containing relations between those 3 classes.
So just define an entity called Collaboration like this:

```
@Entity
public class Collaboration{
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;
  @ManyToOne
  private Task task;
  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;
}
```

With the separated Collaboration entity, you can find all collaborations which have given User.

Without this entity, you can write a query to find all the tasks, which related to the given user and then of course, collect the Projects and Tasks yourself in java code. 
The query will be like

```
 'Select t from Task t join projectUserMap m where m = :user '
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know who downvoted you but it's not me! If you care to explain here, the three tables are linked ?? My point is if i call a query on that table `collaboration` to get **the tasks** and **the projects** of a **given User** I will get them ?

Comment: Ok. I just care if i can help you to understand. The downvote from non-experience users is not a problem for me. Please ask here if something went wrong. I updated my answer regardings your question.

Comment: If my answer fulfill your requirements, please mark it as correct one, because may be others will have the same question in the future

Comment: Yes of corse. I'm just Implementing it and will see.Thanks

Comment: @thanhngo this query doesn't Project and User, it only gives the user. How can we find both Key and Value using a JPQL Query?